# Would the Vulcans defend Earth from a Klingon attack before the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, klingon

In the days of Captain Archer, before there was a Federation of Planets, if the Klingons decided to launch an all out assault on Earth, would the Vulcans rally to our defense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Earth had no mutual defence pact with Vulcan in the era *preceding* the creation of the Coalition of Planets and the UFP. This is most closely evidenced in the days immediately following the Xindi incident in 2153.

Acting on false intelligence from the Sphere Builders, the Xindi launched an attack on Earth with a weapon of mass destruction. Earth requested assistance from the Vulcan High Command and were (evidently) rebuffed. In addition to refusing to send any ships to aid Earth they recalled their sole officer serving aboard a Federation Starship. When she refused, she was stripped her of her rank and dishonourably discharged.

> **T'POL:** *You thought it was crucial to place a Vulcan on Enterprise during its first mission. Why not now?*
>
> **SOVAL:** *You were there to provide logic to a crew of humans who insisted on leaving before they were ready, but logic can't help them
>   inside the Delphic Expanse.*
>
> **T'POL:** *Can you be certain of that?*
>
> **SOVAL:** *The High Command was quite specific. You're to return to Vulcan.*
>
> **T'POL:** *I believe that should be my decision.*
>
> **SOVAL:** *This is not the matter of choice. Defying the High Command would mean immediate dismissal. You know that.*

---

Moving further down the canon scale, the Enterprise novel : [Kobiyashi Maru](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_(novel)) deals extensively with the (*political*) aftermath of the events of the Enterprise TV series, detailing the terms of the [Coalition of Planets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Coalition_of_Planets) in 2155. Membership to this organisation was apparently predicated on a mutual-defense pact between United Earth, the Confederacy of Vulcan, the Andorian Empire and the United Planets of Tellar.

At this point, an attack by the Klingon Empire **would have** resulted in Vulcan ships defending Earth and vice versa.

Comment: i think it also depends on the level of attack, the vulcans didn't help specifically because they feared the delphic expanse, and because they dont think retaliation is usually the answer. however there are a couple of times when the enterprise encountered aggressors and the vulcans came and saved them. if say 1-2 klingon ships showed up at earth and started to attack the planet, the vulcan would have shown up and attempted to talk down, proceed to force the klingons away (the vulcans are more advanced at this time according to enterprise) now if a fleet of klingons showed up...

Comment: the vulcans have a vested interest in earth, and its logical to provide protection as long as the risks to themselves is not elevated.

Comment: @Himarm - The question did relate to an invasion rather than a local incursion. Note that the Vulcans have vested interests on the planet (several embassies and scientific advisors dotted about the place) that they could reasonably claim to be defending without offering an open cheque-book.

Comment: ah, i did miss the full on assault portion of the question.

Comment: Why was their Klingon hostility towards Earth early on in the piece?

Comment: @user16416 - Well, they don't seem the friendly sort, now do they?

Comment: wonder why they never tried to conquer Earth?

Comment: @user16416 - Have you ever been to Earth? It's awfully smelly and messy.

Comment: Klingons are smelly and messy so they should be right at home on planet Earth?

Comment: @user16416 - It's not quite smelly enough for the Klingons but too smelly for the Vulcans.